# How to make sure the user's session is still active in Nodejs?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I am setting user's session on the backend via :

```
req.session.user = req.body.username;
```

and then check on every API request whether this sessions exists or not. Obviously if the session is expired, the user will be redirected to the login page or the request is not made. However, in the meantime the meantime the user can see the previously logged in content until they make an API request. Howe can I make sure that the user's session is active every time without having to set an interval to constantly check it with the server?